# How to Insert multiple rows into single column of database using nodejs router

Tags: angularjs, node.js, db2

I am having trouble inserting multiple rows into a single column where my table name is details.

```
var ticket=req.body.data.ticket;
var tag=req.body.data.tag;
var channel=req.body.data.channel;
var country=req.body.data.country;
var prog=req.body.data.prog;
console.log(prog);

var insertcriteria={ticket:ticket,tag:tag,channel:channel,country:country,prog:prog};
entity.insert('details',insertcriteria).then(function(record){
 }, function(reason) {

                               var errormessage={errormessage:reason};
                                res.json(errormessage);

                            });
```

where prog is an array having more than one value. from console I am getting
prog=[a,b,c,d] on node and I am using DB2.
But during insertion I am getting [object,object] error. Please help  me, how to insert multiple values.

After Insertion my table should be like----[detailsTable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xo5QK.png)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What is your DB2 column type for prog?  Currently you have an array of values which need to be converted to the state you want to persist them in.  The table model you have described doesn't follow 3rd normal form. If you intend on storing this relationally, typically you would create a second table with a ForeignKey back to the details table, and have a 1 - N relationship to this new prog table.  Then you can insert each of the array values into the prog table with the id from the details table and the prog value. If you want to keep it in this state, you would need to insert a row for each prog value, essentially duplicating the other column values or you would convert the array to a string value, concatenating each position in the array with what looks like a carriage return.

Comment: prog is varchar(512) and I am fetching prog values from another table. multiselect drop down selected values getting stored in prog variable.